# Can I legally bypass software when their data is freely available?

Tags: software, licensing, legal-terms, data-ownership

I have built an app on top of an existing ancient software application. That ancient application exists of two parts; a software application and some actual hardware that provides specific sensor data that is shown inside that application. That data is provided over RS232 and is just raw and freely available.

I just put a splitter cable between the sensor and the existing application. And from there on I use that data to be used in my own app.

The customers of this ancient software application buy their software and hardware sensors. All I do is provide these same customers an option to view the same data but via an app, for a small monthly fee ofcourse.

The creator of the ancient software application caught wind of this and now says: hey, this is forbidden, you can't do this and you need to stop.

So the question is; the data is available. I don't touch their software, I simply bypass it. Can they actually make me stop? Do they have any say in this?

Comment: If the data is freely available why don't you simply buy hardware sensors separately?  And you say the data is freely available, but also say is it "their" data, which implies it is proprietary, and there are probably terms and conditions associated with purchase of their product.  And which seemingly contradicts "freely available"...

Comment: This sounds like something where you **need** a lawyer in your jurisdiction. If you think that asking this on the web is a good idea, that's a clear sign that you need expert legal advice.

Comment: @ o.m. I was going to ask a lawyer anyway but just wanted to get a feel.
@MichaelHall The data comes from sensors they installed. Buying these hardware sensors gets me into the 'hardware department' of the business; I don't like that. I am a software developer so I like to keep it to just the app instead of installing hardware senors I have no knowledge about.

Comment: How is something "freely available", that you have to buy from a specific vendor, signing their contracts? Also, do you market your product using their company name? Do you say "This allows you a companion app for $AncientSoft's Application"?

Comment: If the data is truly free why don't you simply find another means to gather it?  Or does their hardware process the data in a unique way?  Because that's a different thing, is it not?  Something doesn't feel right here...

Comment: Can you elaborate in what way the data is freely available? Raw RS232 data is just bytes without any meaning. How were you able to attach meaning to those bytes being transferred (and the speed at which it happens)?

Comment: Where is this? in hte US reveser engineering to duplicate a software interface is legal...

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Exactly. I found meaning to those bytes, in all fairness; it's very basic data and they even explained it in their documentation so that wasn't hard to decypher. @ Michael Hall - I am not trying to do anything fishy at all. By freely available I meant; I can just read the data that comes out of their sensors. I did not 'crack' or 'hack' anything. I plug in a USB cable and voila; data. I can't get any other means to gather this data besides creating my own sensors; I'd rather not go that route because customers already have working sensors. They wouldn't want to switch.

Comment: @Questor It's in Europe, Netherlands.

Comment: In the Netherlands, reverse engineering for purposes of software interoperability (IE allowing so that your software can interact with someone elses software/hardware) is legal. And it is actually against the law to have a ToS that prevents it... Not a lawyer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely legally never use the manufacturer's software. But you need to consider:

- Whether, if you have used their software in the past, you agreed to a contract where you promised not to bypass it, or to develop tools to bypass it.
- Whether bypassing the software would void your license to use that software concurrently or in the future.
- Whether not bypassing the software was a condition of the purchase agreement for the hardware.
- Whether the original company is actually just lending you the hardware, on the condition you only talk to it with their software, per some agreement they waved about when installing it.
- Whether the original company will refuse to provide support to or do business with anyone who they find out uses your product.

So what you want to do is either perfectly fine, or not allowed because you "agreed" not to do it, but it's impossible to tell which without an enumeration of all the agreements in play.

Comment: I do not think the OP wants to use the other company's software.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I think OP said they had a splitter cable connecting the device, the original software, and their better software all together.